# How to get to a particular child of a parent which is clicked?

Tags: jquery, html

I am accessing the sub links under a list item of links. [3 level hierarchy ]

Each link can have sub links with little arrow head showing ,that contains sub links.

When its clicked , i need to show the div with list of sub links . 
Now the issue is , when i click ,any link (list item) with sub link is opening.

Below is the sample code generated from xslt and page contains n number of list items like below

```
      <li>
        <div>
          <table>
            <tbody><tr style="background-color:#F6FBFF;vertical-align:middle">
              <td style="text-align: center;background-color:#F6FBFF;width:13px;height:22px">
                <div class="childLevelCollapse" data-state="closed">
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <a href="s.aspx">Ex-offenders</a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody></table>
        </div>
        <div style="display: block;" class="childUI">
          <ul style=" background-color:#DEECF7;">
            <li style="margin-left:1em">
              <a href="s.aspx">TEST</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
```

Code to toggle

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.display').click(function () {
        if($(this).attr("data-state") == "open")
        {      
            $(this).attr("class", "childLevelCollapse");
            $(this).attr("data-state", "closed");   
            $(".childUI").hide(); //this works but hides all sub links      
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).attr("class", "childLevelExpand");
            $(this).attr("data-state", "open");
            $(".childUI").show();//this works but opens all sub links
            $(this).closest('.div1').children('.childUI').slideToggle('slow');//tried 
            $(this).parent().siblings(".childUI");//tried 
            $(this).parents(".div1").children(".childUI");//tried 
            $(this).closest(".div1").find('[class*="childUI"]').first().show();//tried 
            // working but always opens the first list item with sublinks , i know it says .first(). i want to open the list item which is currently clicked
            $(this).closest(".div1").find('[class*="childUI"]').first().slideToggle('slow');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

css

```
 <style>
.childUI
{
    display:none;

}
.childLevelCollapse
{
    height:14px;
    width:12px;
    background:url('/images/Navarrow1.gif') no-repeat 0px 5px;display:inline-block;
}
.childLevelExpand
{
    height:14px;
    width:12px;
    background:url('/images/Navarrow2.gif') no-repeat 0px 5px;display:inline-block;
}
</style>
```

Something like below
[image]

**UPDATE**

I removed all the table structure and the below line worked

```
  $(this).parent('.div2').children('.childUI').slideToggle('slow');
```

Comment: Are you after the nth-child() selector??

Comment: Where is `class="display"` in your HTML?

Comment: Don't use `.attr("class", "newClass")`, because that will replace all the classes, including `display`. Use `.addClass`, `.removeClass`, or `.toggleClass`.

Comment: class=display will be replaced when any item is clicked for first item

Comment: @stackunderflow something similar , but need the item which is clicked

Comment: @Vani If you found a solution to your problem, the best practice is to post an answer yourself and then accept that answer when it is possible to do so.